# Newbie question on Macro photography kit

Tags: macro

I am newbie here and would like to know what is required to take macro photography. I have seen pictures of flies and insects that are taken very close and they show a lot of details. I would like to take such photographs. I have a D90 and a 18-55 lens that came along with the camera. I have tried to take macro using this lens, by getting close to the object, but could not get the desired results. So please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the insect closeup, you will need a prime lens and is a dedicated 1:1 macro lens, like the 50mm, 100mm, or 180mm. Even though these lens provide good results, you can add more magnification by adding extension tubes. Extension tubes are hollow tubes that sit between the camera body and the lens. But by using extension tubes, you could find difficult focusing some close up objects (I had this problem). It takes some practice and you will eventually get close to the insects brain :).

Also check these photography threads (there are more, if you could only search) in SE for more details:

- [What do I need for extreme macro photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41576/what-do-i-need-for-extreme-macro-photography/41618#41618)
- [How to micro-adjust distance for focusing in macro photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5227/how-to-micro-adjust-distance-for-focusing-in-macro-photography)

TIP: BE sure to search the forums before asking questions, chances are that your questions has already been asked.

Good luck, HTH.